# How do I flatten multi level pandas DF?

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns

thanks for taking the time to read my question!

When I get some stock data from an API i get them back in a pandas Dataframe. This works fine for me to process when I request 1 symbol, but when I request more then 1 symbol i get lost :) :

[image: df return with 3 symbols]

It seems it adds an extra layer of columns with the symbol names and below that have the usualstock data
columns OHLC & Volume

What I would like is to get this data in the following format:

Date - Security - High - Close - Low - Open - Volume.

So have the symbols all vertically instead of horizontally and an extra column with the symbol name to keep them apart.

Could anyone help me out here how to handle this? Or point me in the right direction?

Thank you very much,
Jan

Here is the csv data I get when i export to csv using the pandas writer:

```
Security,RDSa.AS,RDSa.AS,RDSa.AS,RDSa.AS,RDSa.AS,NESN.S,NESN.S,NESN.S,NESN.S,NESN.S,RO.S,RO.S,RO.S,RO.S,RO.S
Field,HIGH,CLOSE,LOW,OPEN,VOLUME,HIGH,CLOSE,LOW,OPEN,VOLUME,HIGH,CLOSE,LOW,OPEN,VOLUME
Date,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
2020-06-01,14.7,14.682,14.376,14.58,11787104.0,,,,,,,,,,
2020-06-02,15.238,15.188,14.828,14.87,18512461.0,104.8,102.92,102.92,104.42,6564417.0,337.4,335.6,330.4,337.4,54616.0
2020-06-03,15.928,15.822,15.412,15.412,26078384.0,104.1,103.86,102.62,103.4,6209773.0,338.6,337.6,334.4,338.0,29417.0
2020-06-04,15.944,15.648,15.474,15.8,16866136.0,104.62,102.76,102.56,103.02,7061646.0,341.0,330.8,328.6,338.0,41448.0
```

so this:

[image]

into this:

[image]

Comment: FYI - its good practice to post a small clip of your data (copy & paste), not a screenshot of code or data - I am struggling to have a crack at this, maybe read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: thanks for your input! I added a part of the CSV data in a block :)

Answer (score 0):

you can access to a specific level of dataframe columns and replace it

```
df.columns = df.columns.get_level_values(0)
```

Comment: Thank you! Would it be possible to select lets say the HIGH,LOW,CLOSE,OPEN,VOLUME columns for only the symbol RDSa.AS for example,
so I can loop over all symbols and put them in another Dataframe which is in the from i want it in?

Comment: df['RDSa.AS'].columns.get_level_values(0)

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to do this is by using the get_level_values as Pierock suggested thank you. In this case:

print(df.iloc[:, df.columns.get_level_values(0)=='RDSa.AS])

did the trick